# Indent Latex algorithm numbering

Tags: formatting, indentation, algorithms, algorithmic

I am using algorithm and algorithmic package to right the algorithm. But at some point, indentation in the numbering of the algorithm got mixed up please see the code and image.

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\caption{Decision Tree induction algorithm}
\Function{TreeGrowth}{$E,F$}
\If{$stopping\_cod(E,F) = true$}
\State \emph{leaf}=createNode()
\State \emph{leaf}.label=\(\displaystyle Classify(E) \)
\State return $\emph{leaf}$
\Else
\State root =\(\displaystyle CreateNode() \)
\State root.test_cond=\(\displaystyle find\_best\_split(E,F) \)
\State let \(\displaystyle V \)={\(\displaystyle v|v \) is a possible outcome of \(\displaystyle root.test\_cond\)}
\For{ each $v$ $\in$ $V$ }
\State $E_v$= \{$\emph{e}$\|root.test\_cond($e$)=$v$\,and\,\\\hspace{.02cm} $\emph{e}$\in $E$\}
\State $\emph{child}$ = $TreeGrowth(E_v,F)$
\State add \emph{child} as descendent of \emph{root} and label the end (\emph{root} $\to$ $\emph{child}$ as $\emph{v}$
\EndFor
\EndIf
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

[image: Output of the algorithm]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Unfortunately, the image is not visible.

Comment: Thank You Bernard, I did everything I could to add the image but instead the link below my question appears. Can you please help on how to go about adding the image ?

Comment: I've fixed.  Next time, remember that, to highlight code, it is better (and simpler) to select it in the edit window and click on the pair of braces in the toolbar.

Comment: Thank you very much Bernard, highly appreciated.

Comment: It would improve your question further if you make the code complete, i.e., add the documentclass, packages, begin/end document, such that when the code is copied in a new document and compiled it shows exactly the output that you have now. This is important because the documentclass and the packages can change the layout and default behavior of the `algorithmic` environment, so the complete code is potentially very relevant for finding out what the problem is and testing out a solution.